# Laravel Mailable problem - multiple calls

Tags: laravel, laravel-mail

I noticed randomly I get this error "Trying to get property 'email' of non-object" when I want to send an email using this code:

```
Mail::to($email)->send(new TicketEmail($item, $request->response, "0"));
```

When I checked the logs I found out that Laravel calls Mailable and setAddress functions three times! And in two of them, it sends an empty array as an email address. How's it possible?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was the env file, I replaced MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS and MAIL_FROM_NAME with their values in TicketEmail.php and the problem is gone!